# Что происходит в этой строке?: outs = (rem > 0) ? " + " + rem + outs : outs;

Tags: java, алгоритм, if, for, тернарный-оператор

Что происходит в этой строке?:

```
outs = (rem > 0) ? " + " + rem + outs : outs;
```

Весь код:

```
public class Kata
{
    public static String expandedForm(int num)
    {
        String outs = "";
        for (int i = 10; i < num; i *= 10) {
            int rem = num % i;
            outs = (rem > 0) ? " + " + rem + outs : outs;
            num -= rem;
        }
        outs = num + outs;

        return outs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тернарный оператор.

```
outs = (rem > 0) ? " + " + rem + outs : outs;
```

Если `rem > 0`, эта строка превращается в

```
outs = " + " + rem + outs;
```

В противном случае она имеет вид

```
outs = outs;
```

В общем случае выражение

```
a ? b : c
```

имеет значение `b`, если `a` истинно, и `c`, если ложно.

Comment: Спасибо большое)